# Is there is an easy way to prove $\tan(2x) = 2$ has a solution?

Tags: trigonometry

I am stuck on the problem of whether $\tan(2x)=2$ has at least one root.

I can rewrite this expression to:

$$\frac{\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^{2}(x)-\sin^{2}(x)} = 1$$

But can't seem to make it simpler to prove, that there is at least one solution, i.e. at least one root. Is this the right approach?

Comment: You're asking if $\arctan(2)$ is defined. The range of $\tan$ is $[-\infty, \infty]$ so clearly it is.

Comment: @egglog did you mean domain of $\arctan$?(fixed now)

Comment: @egglog Do you mean the range of $\tan$?

Comment: Just drawing the graph of tan(2x) and seeing if it intersects the line y=2 will also work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restrict your attention to $x\in(-\pi/2,\pi/2)$. Then note that
$$\tan(\pi/4)=1<2$$
and that
$$\tan(3\pi/8)=1+\sqrt{2}>2$$
And, $\tan$ is continuous (exercise) so there must be a solution to $\tan(x)=2$ somewhere in between.

Comment: For OP: a half angle identity can be used for $\tan$ to evaluate at $\frac{3\pi}{8}$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function $f(x)= \tan(2x)-2$. Then $f$ is a continuous function on $[0,\frac{\pi}{4})$. Now $f(0)=\tan(0)-2=-2$.

We know that $\lim_{x \to\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan(x) = +\infty$. So, $\lim_{x \to\frac{\pi}{2}}\tan(2x)=+\infty$. So, $ \lim_{x \to\frac{\pi}{2}}f(x)=+\infty$

So there is a $x\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ such that $f(x)>10$( 10 is symbolic here, actually given any positive real number $M$, you can find a real number $x_0\in [0,\frac{\pi}{4})$ with $f(x)>M$).

Now you apply intermediate value property to to claim that $\exists x\in [0,x_0] $ such that $f(x)=0$. So, you get a root.